# XSLT - Convert multiple tags of same type to blocks using the last set header value

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to get all elements after a header and before the next header enclosed by the header names.

I have an Xml which looks like this:

```
<Main>
  <Sec>
    <Header>A</Header>
    <Body>A1</Body>
  </Sec>
  <Sec>
    <Body>A2</Body>
  </Sec>
  <Sec>
    <Header>B</Header>
    <Body>B1</Body>
  </Sec>
  <Sec>
    <Body>B2</Body>
  </Sec>
  <Sec>
    <Body>B3</Body>
  </Sec>
</Main>
```

I want to convert the above Xml to this format:

```
<Main>
  <Sec>
    <Type1>A1</Type1>
    <Type1>A2</Type1>
    <Type2>B1</Type2>
    <Type2>B2</Type2>
    <Type2>B3</Type2>
  </Sec>
</Main>
```

Type1 and Type2 are fixed so we don't need to get tag names from the header tag.

I am new to Xml and can't figure out how to do this using basic controls. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a fairly standard grouping question, and the answer depends very much on whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0+. Read up on grouping in your favourite XSLT textbook.

Comment: I was able to do this in XSLT 2.0 but it turns out my project requires 1.0.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 will be the COBOL of the future: old technologies never die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following **XSLT 2.0** solution uses [`xsl:for-each-group`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#element-for-each-group) to select all of the `Body` elements and group them by the first `Header` along the [`preceding::`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#doc-xpath-ReverseAxis) axis.

For each of those groups of `Body` elements, it constructs the name of the "type" element using the `Header` value. I used [`string-to-codepoints()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-to-codepoints) to convert the letters `A` and `B` into their codepoint numbers 65 and 66, and then subtract 1. You could use a lookup, or a set of if/else or `xsl:choose` if the magic formula is confusing or your actual data doesn't allow for the simple calculation.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    
  <xsl:template match="Main">
    <xsl:copy>
      <Sec>
        <xsl:for-each-group group-by="preceding::Header[1]" select=".//Body">
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <xsl:element name="type{string-to-codepoints(current-grouping-key()) - 64}">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </Sec>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This **XSLT 1.0** solution also generates the desired output. Instead of using `string-to-codepoints()`, it uses the `translate()` function to translate `A` into `1` and `B` into `2`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    
  <xsl:template match="Main">
    <xsl:copy>
      <Sec>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Body"/>
      </Sec>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Body">       
    <xsl:element name="type{translate(preceding::Header[1], 'AB','12')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It works although I just learned that my project requires xslt 1.0. Thanks for this.